# Git on Windows - tutorial?

Tags: windows, git, documentation

- Does anyone know of a decent tutorial on how to set up Git on Windows?
- Which client do you prefer to use? Any that integrates with Visual Studio?
- How to use Git on windows? I am used to svn and sourcesafe but a complete newbie to Git.

Comment: the title of your question is misleading: you are not searching a "tutorial", you are searching for "install instructions". i would change the title and the question to reflect that.

Comment: Changed the question. I am also looking on how to learn how to use Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Windows** Users...: 
This tutorial [here](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/05/12/starting-and-using-git-successfully.aspx)  gets you up and running in a simple and concise manner. He teaches you the most useful command line routines and simple GIT workflows that you will use over and over again.

Cheers!

Comment: +1 it's a nice link-to-links, although I don't agree with the necessity for github

Comment: also, you shouldn't use `rebase` *before* having used branches and `merge` for a while

Comment: ...use bitbucket.org for private repos. In Github, they cost but not in Bitbucket.org so easy to test git for example on school work etc.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [msysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/). What's a better `git` client than `git` itself? (Don't forget to `git config --global color.diff always`.)

For Visual Studio integration, try [Git Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) and check out this StackOverflow post: [Using Git with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Here's [another guide](http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/about.html) to using Git on Windows. msysGit appears to be fine, although I prefer to use [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) - but then I'm not really a full-fledged programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at a similar [question at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682762/where-can-i-download-gcc-binaries-for-windows)